# Why is the message never delivered?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

For some reason, i never get the message back from the server to the client :/ whats happening? how can i know or solve this?

I send the request from the client, the server gets that request, process it and generate a response that is send. But the client never reads it.

```
public class Client {

private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 13579;
        System.out.println("Conecting to : " + host + ":" + port);
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        socket = new Socket(address, port);

        //Send the message to the server
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        String sendMessage = "103700635105281047295162150000001418    99900001000000717999000NovoTransactionsBusiness 717          VE000000000054300052810472900000000000099900001                  1803\n";

        bw.write(sendMessage);
        bw.flush();
        System.out.println("Message sent to the server : " + sendMessage);

        //Get the return message from the server
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
   //But i never get the message back
        String message = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Message received from the server : " + message);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //Closing the socket
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

The server is running fine!

```
public class Server {

private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int port = 13579;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Servidor Iniciado escuchando al puerto " + port);
        while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            String strRequest = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).readLine();
            System.out.println("Request Received: " + strRequest);
            String returnMessage;
            try {
                returnMessage = new NovoTrans().init(strRequest).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                returnMessage = "Error: " + e.getMessage() + "\n";
            }
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            bw.write(returnMessage);
            System.out.println("Sending Message: " + returnMessage);
            bw.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is the return message always terminated with a new line? if not the client's call to `readLine()` could be blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) instead of `BufferedWriter`. There is no need to call flush after each line and simply use `println()` method along with **auto-flush** feature to add a new line as well.

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the `println`, `printf`, or `format` methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output.
>
> These methods use the platform's own notion of line separator rather than the newline character.

There is no need to append `\n` in the message itself.

Sample code: (Do the changes in both server and client side classes)

```
// here true means auto flush when `println()` method is called
PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()),true);
bw.println(returnMessage);
```